# How handle Dynamic JSON in angular component

Tags: json, angular, typescript, angular14

I have JSON file which contains themes related to my angular application. This is the JSON file.

### Theme 1

```
 {
        "mpaStyle": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/style/vintageStyle.json",
        "mapCSS": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/style/vintageStyle.CSS",
        "mapSources": [
            {
                "name": "ship",
                "obj": {
                    "type": "image",
                    "url": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/sprite_images/ship.png",
                    "coordinates": [
                        [
                            -1.828685,
                            66.044102
                        ],
                        [
                            2.609791,
                            66.044102
                        ],
                        [
                            2.609791,
                            64.177497
                        ],
                        [
                            -1.828685,
                            64.177497
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            }
        ],
        "mapExternalComponents": [
            "<div id='compass' style ='position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 200px; z-index: 2; background-image: url('img/compass.png'); background-size: 200px 200px;'></div>"
        ],
        "markerImg": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/sprite_images/marker.png"
    }
```

### Theme 2

```
 {
        "mpaStyle": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/style/vintageStyle.json",
        "mapCSS": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/style/vintageStyle.CSS",
        
        "mapExternalComponents": [
            "<div id='compass' style ='position: absolute; top: 20px; left: 20px; width: 200px; height: 200px; z-index: 2; background-image: url('img/compass.png'); background-size: 200px 200px;'></div>"
        ],
        "markerImg": "assets/mapreport/themes/vintage/sprite_images/marker.png"
    }
```

Here I have added two JSON file. In first JSON file has `mapSources` array. Its contains some objects. This mapSources is not added to the 2 nd theme. In such a case how can I dynamically pass data to the component.

The 2nd question : `mapExternalComponents` contains HTML elements. so how can I pass this HTML element to the component and show it in the HTML page.

Answer (score 0):

To dynamically pass data to a component in Angular, you can use @Input(). First define @Input() in the correct component to accept data from the parent component. Here's how to pass data dynamically:

In the component that needs to receive the data, add "@Input()":

```
export class YourComponent {
  @Input() themeData: any;
}
```

Then, in the parent component, pass the data to the child component:

```
<app-your-compoennt [themeData]="selectedTheme"></app-your-compoennt>
```

In the parent component, you also need to define a selectedTheme property that will contain the theme data you want to pass.

As for your second question, if you want to display HTML from mapExternalComponents, you can use the [innerHTML] directive in the component template. Here's how to display this HTML in a component:

In your-component.component.html add:

```
<div [innerHTML]="themeData.mapExternalComponents[0]"></div>
```

Note that directly inserting HTML can lead to XSS vulnerabilities. If you are sure that the HTML is safe then you can use this method. Otherwise, think about sanitizing the HTML before displaying it on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. suppose if we removed mapSources from the JSON object. then how can I identify it. is there any way to created dynamic object to handle this JSON.